# File is not upload on server in android?

Tags: android, image-uploading

i am getting the image from sdcard and after that i upload the image on the server but image is not uploading on the server

```
public class ImageUploadActivity extends Activity 
{

    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    Button submitbutton;

    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    String upLoadServerUri = null;



    String uploadfilenewname;

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.addpost);


            uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonupload);
            submitbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsubmit);
            messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texttitle);

            upLoadServerUri = "http://202.131.110.186/celol_local/index.php/webservices/userposts";

            uploadButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonupload);
            uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {   
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent a = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(a, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                }
            });

            submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {


                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImageUploadActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                        }
                                    });                      

                                //uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                               uploadFile(uploadfilenewname);
                            }
                          }).start();        
                    }
                });


        }



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
            {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                uploadfilenewname = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                Log.e("Upload file Name","-->"+uploadfilenewname);
                cursor.close();             


            }


        }






        public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) 
        {      
              String fileName = sourceFileUri;
              HttpURLConnection conn = null;
              DataOutputStream dos = null; 
              String lineEnd = "\r\n";
              String twoHyphens = "--";
              String boundary = "*****";
              int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
              byte[] buffer;
              int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
              File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);


              if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                   dialog.dismiss();

                   Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+uploadfilenewname);

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                   {
                       public void run()
                       {

                           messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" +uploadfilenewname);
                       }
                   });

                   return 0;

              }
              else
              {
                   try {

                         // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                       URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                       // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                       conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                       conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                       conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                       conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                       dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                               + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                       // create a buffer of  maximum size
                       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                       // read file and write it into form...
                       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

                       while (bytesRead > 0) {

                         dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                        }

                       // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                       // Responses from the server (code and message)
                       serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                       String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                       Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                               + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                       if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                                  +uploadfilenewname;

                                    messageText.setText(msg);
                                    Toast.makeText(ImageUploadActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });               
                       }   

                       //close the streams //
                       fileInputStream.close();
                       dos.flush();
                       dos.close();

                  } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                      dialog.dismiss(); 
                      ex.printStackTrace();

                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {
                              messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                              Toast.makeText(ImageUploadActivity.this, "MalformedURLException",
                                                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });

                      Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
                  } catch (Exception e) {

                      dialog.dismiss(); 
                      e.printStackTrace();

                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {
                              messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                              Toast.makeText(ImageUploadActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });
                      Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                       + e.getMessage(), e); 
                  }
                  dialog.dismiss();      
                  return serverResponseCode;

               } // End else block
             } 

    }
```

Comment: you can check it onactivityresult i got the full path of image 10-24 /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Facebook/IMG_3686759002691.jpeg
i direct put this path in uploadfile function

Comment: What is the response from server?

Comment: 10-24 17:26:57.820: E/uploadFile(21920): HTTP Response is : Not Found: 404

Comment: 404 is Your url is not working , check it on browser. http://202.131.110.186/celol_local/index.php/webservices/userposts

Comment: ok but i have name and title also with parameter which is not except

Comment: conn.setRequestProperty("id", id);
                 conn.setRequestProperty("title", title);
                 conn.setRequestProperty("description", description);